# Strangely colored boot backgrounds after crash of stock 6.0.1

Tags: nexus-5, 6.0-marshmallow

A few days ago my Nexus 5 running stock Android Marshmellow 6.0.1 crashed. Some application, I think it was Google Maps, got 'stuck' in an animation, after which the phone shut down. It wouldn't reboot until I connected the power adapter (despite the battery being at 50+%).

Ever since then, when I boot the phone, the background is bright green instead of the usual black. The edges of the boot animation are slightly jagged and when the home screen is initially shown, the colors are all weird, as in a old photo negative. A single button press redraws the screen and after that everything works fine.

To be absolutely clear about that last part: the phone is completely functional, except for the weird boot background colors described in the previous and following paragraphs.

I do no succeed in entering recovery mode: the phone only shows a plain coloured background. If I press the power button once in that state, the phone does boot, suggesting it actually is in recovery mode, but I just can't see the menu.

Now for an interesting thing: the background colour varies between 4 or 5 different colours. I've seen the same green as during 'regular' boot, but also a bright blue, a blue-green, a somewhat purple blue and a yellow-brownish background (I'm not certain all blues are actually different, there are at least 2, maybe 3)).

The same colors are shown when, during boot, I press the power button and keep it pressed until the boot sequence is interrupted and the phone reboots. If I repeat the rebooting a couple of times, the colour of the background may differ from reboot to reboot. Sometimes the same shade of blue appears 4 times in a row, sometimes followed by a green, rarely by the yellow-brown, etc.

It's a complete mystery to me what is going on. Google doesn't give me any useful results and I cannot find any documentation that explains what is going on. Has any of you seen this and can you explain how I can get out of this situation?

Bumped on 2016-03-26